# Find the last value of a matching column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to pull the last value of a matching column, but I'm finding increasingly issues and building a troubling long formula. Imagine I want to pull the last price for Fish.

So far I have

```
=MATCH(Crafts!A20,$1:$1,0) --> 3
```

Then

```
=INDEX($1:$1000,3,MATCH(Crafts!A20,$1:$1,0)) --> 25
```

This index formula is working when I give it a manual row. However, I don't know how to find the last value in that column so it returns 22.

COUNTA doesn't work as it ignores blanks. I could do COUNTA + COUNTBLANK, but they need a range, and I only have the MATCH, which returns a column index, not the column range.

[image]

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution myself and it was indeed easier than expected, just needed a bit of a workaround.

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,INDEX($1:$1001,,MATCH(Crafts!A20,$1:$1,0)))
```

By removing the ROW index in the INDEX formula, it returns an array, the entire column. By performing a LOOKUP of a huge number, it just returns whatever the last value of the array is.

Works, and it's cleaner than everything else I tried, by far.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("C"&MAX((ROW(C:C))*(C:C<>""))))
```

**Update**

Assuming cell Crafts!A20 = `Fish - White` and the desired output is in the same sheet as input `Fish - White` column then:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(
 ADDRESS(1,         MATCH(Crafts!A20, 1:1, )), "1", )&MAX(ROW(A:A))*(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(1,         MATCH(Crafts!A20, 1:1, ))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(Crafts!A20, 1:1, )))<>"")))
```

Comment: Can't, because C is not always C, it's dynamic and given by the MATCH, which returns 3 (not C). 
Already tried going down that route. Then also tried converting that 3 into the C:C range using ADDRESS(), but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: @Chaoscontrol answer updated